# JQuery. Исключить из набора вложенный элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста. Никак не могу справиться с таким заданием:

```
<div class="test1">
    <div class="common-text">
        <p>Много текста</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        Меню
    </div>
    <div class="more">
        <div class="links">
            Ссылки
        </div>
        <div class="tags">
            Тэги
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

С помощью JQuery необходимо взять весь текст внутри класса .test1, за исключением текста в классе .tags.

Пробовал и :not и .filter и :has. Комбинировал по разному. Не выходит:

```
var text = $(".test1").contents().filter(":not(.tags)").text();
```

Comment: в вопросе синтаксическая ошибка - нет кавычек после `.test1`

Comment: как именно пробовал? что значит _не выходит_?

Comment: Ответ Umer полностью мне подходит, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Незнаю каков смысл этой задачи, но вот:

```
$(".test1").find("div:not(.tags)").filter(":not(.more)").text()
```

**UPDATE**:
    или так

```
$(".test1").find("div:not(.tags):not(.more)").text()
```

Comment: в чем смысла вызова _filter_?

Comment: @Grundy . find("div:not(.tags)") найдет все дивы включая .more. filter(":not(.more)") исключит его из выборки

Comment: а зачем его исключать?

Comment: @Grundy чтоб выполнить условие задачи :) исключить текст в классе .tags

Comment: _div:not(.tags)_ а вот это его разве не исключит?

Comment: @Grundy исключит. Но родительский котейнер .more тоже подходит под условие div:not(.tags). Поэтому он окажется в выборке а внутри него лежит .tags

Comment: @Grundy вы правы, можно скоратить вот так jQuery(".test1").find("div:not(.tags):not(.more)").text()

Answer (score 0):

Можно обернуть `html` тега в jQuery-коллекцию и удалить оттуда DOM-узел `.tags`

```js
var text = $($(".test1").html());
text.find('.tags').remove();
text = text.text();
document.body.appendChild($('<div style="color:red">Вывод: ' + text + '</div>').get(0));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">
    <div class="common-text">
        <p>Много текста</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        Меню
    </div>
    <div class="more">
        <div class="links">
            Ссылки
        </div>
        <div class="tags">
            Тэги
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Работает, всё хорошо. Благодарю.